# Strange shading fragments on mesh

Tags: modeling, shaders, normals

can anyone help me?

I've just finished texturing a model I made. After I import the mesh and the textures in UE4, I've encountered this shading fragments.

This are screenshots on UE4:

[image: UE4Screencap3]

[image: UE4Screencap2]

[image: UE4Screencap4]

[image: UE4Screencap5]

This is how it looks like in substance painter:

[image: SubstancePainterScreenCap2]

And this is the model on blender:

[image: BlenderScreenCap1]

EDIT:
I'm not too sure with the all quads solution.
I've tried ripping a part of the model that is all quads but it's still giving me weird shading.

New blender screen capture:
[image]
[image]

Comment: They all appear where there are tris so you should try to make all quad base geometry

Comment: All quads? Alright. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Some of the fragments were removed when I made the edges sharp and added an edge split modifier then baked the normals using that mesh as the low poly. But some of the fragments are still there, so I'm going to try making those parts quads

Comment: If you have a simpler version with everything quad, maybe you can try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rlMzsBWtPY

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to your question could be that you need to try and make geometry that defines the shape of your  all quads and then, around corners, add edge loops to surround those defining points (namely sharp corners, etc.). Then, after that, mark those edges (not the esge loops) as creases. It should work after that. Using a subsurf modifier should help on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

Normal baking is complicated thing. I'm think, usually your Low-poly must good look wihout normal map before baking. Not have bad shading. So you can for example add some bevels or sharp edges as you wrote. Also try to make quads flat in problem areas.
 You can check out this: https://polycount.com/discussion/81154/understanding-averaged-normals-and-ray-projection-who-put-waviness-in-my-normal-map

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using edge loops or setting edges to sharp, use the auto smooth [auto smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/meshes/structure.html#auto-smooth) option and set to angle to ~80 degrees. This should help with the weird shading artifacts.